# Swift 2.0 iOS rotating text keeping characters vertical

Tags: ios, string, swift, text, rotation

I have seen lots of examples of how to rotate text so that the characters change angle with the string, but what if I want to rotate a string, having each character remain parallel to the horizontal plane (X-Axis)?

E.G., for a vertical string, I would like the text "Hello" to render:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

Not "Hello" with a rotated baseline.  Is this possible without having to create a multiline text, or even a lot of one character texts?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to rotate the whole button.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 4))
```

This rotates the button 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it without multiline text or one character labels but you can could create a bunch of one character labels and use a stack view to line them up and keep them together. If you have any graphics apps, you could also just create them in there and bring them in as images. You don't get text manipulation from that though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping
```